# How to find max value in nested array nd update it?

Tags: javascript, mongodb

the document is:

```
var house = {
"name": name1,
"steps":[
    {
      "step_id":1,
      "value":9999,
      "members": [
        {
           "user_id": 7,
         },
         {
           "user_id": 1
        }
      ]
   },
   {
      "step_id":6,
       "value":9999,
      "members": [
        {
           "user_id": 7,
         },
         {
           "user_id": 1
        }
      ]
   }
}
```

}

All I need to do is to find document by name, find there step with MAX "step_id" value and update there "value" field to -1;

I tried this but it doesnt' work for me. will be glad for any help :)

```
   db.collection('houses').find( {"name": "name1",max: { $max : "steps.$step_id" },{$set:{"steps.$.value":-1}, function (err, doc) {
                if(err){
                    return
                }

                console.log('doc updated');
            } );
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) and return for every loop the object with the greater `step_id`.

Then update the property.

```js
var house = { name: "name1", steps:[{ step_id: 1, value: 9999, "members": [{ user_id: 7 }, { user_id: 1 }] }, { step_id: 6, value: 9999, members: [{ user_id: 7 }, { user_id: 1 }] }] };

house.steps.reduce((a, b) => a.step_id > b.step_id ? a : b).value = -1;

console.log(house);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```